# How do I create a branch with libgit2

Tags: branch, libgit2

How do I create a branch using the libgit2 library, the API has reference to a commit target, but what should I use for this parameter?

This is the code I have got so far, based on example code in tests, but they use many hard coded references so its difficult to discover what you should use in a real-world scenario like what i should pass as 'target' in this instance.

```
git_reference *branch = NULL, *head = NULL;

/* Create the branch */
git_branch_create( &branch, open_repo, "MyNewBranch", target, 0 );

/* Make HEAD point to this branch */
git_reference_symbolic_create( &head, open_repo, "HEAD", git_reference_name( branch ), 1 );
git_reference_free( head );
git_reference_free( branch );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what i should pass as 'target' in this instance.

The resolved commit that you'd like your new branch to point to.

As stated in the **[header](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/branch.h)**

> @param target **Object to which this branch should point.** This object
>   must belong to the given `repo` and can either be a git_commit or a
>   git_tag. When a git_tag is being passed, it should be dereferencable
>   to a git_commit which oid will be used as the target of the branch.

**Note:** Surprisingly, the header is not in sync with the code. The header makes the reader think that passing a `git_object` would be fine. However, only a `git_commit` is accepted.

### Update

> And how would i get 'the resolved commit';

- Provided you know the oid of the commit, `git_commit_lookup()` would be the way to go.
- If you're already having a hold on a `git_object` which happens to be a commit (`git_object_type()` returns `GIT_OBJ_COMMIT`), you could just cast it and pass `(git_commit *)my_object` to the function.

Comment: And how would i get 'the resolved commit'; apologies if I am being bit dim, but I am not writing a full-on client, just adding git capabilities to my editor so my knowledge is limited on using libgit

Comment: Thanks, I called: git_reference_name_to_id( &oid_parent_commit, open_repo, "HEAD" ); then git_commit_lookup( &last_commit, open_repo, &oid_parent_commit ); ... it worked, so I am hoping it was the right thing to do.

Comment: The git2/branch.h has just been **[fixed](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1452)** ;-)

Comment: So this is how we create a local branch, but how do we create a remote branch?